# Explicit template instantiation and forwarding references

Tags: c++, templates, explicit-instantiation, forwarding-reference

Recently, I was discussing with students the possibilities of **restriction of types for templates** that uses **forwarding references**. I knew about comparing types by `is_same` together with `static_assert` or `enable_if`, but we also talked about **explicit template instantiation**.

The following example works for me with GCC:

**f.h:**

```
template <typename T>              
void f(T&& param); // declaration
```

**f.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void f(T&& param) { std::cout << param << std::endl; }

// explicit instantiations:
template void f<int>(int&&);
template void f<int&>(int&);
```

**main.cpp:**

```
#include "f.h"      

int main() { 
   f(1);              
// f('1'); // LINKER ERROR   

   int i = 2;         
   f(i);              
}
```

I am not an expert in explicit template instantiations, so I just wonder **whether such a solution is portable/standard-compliant**. (*Please, do not ask me about use cases, I don't have any. For me, it's purely an academic question.*)

**UPDATE**

I am also a bit confused about the format of the explicit instantiation (`<int>(int&&)` and `<int&>(int&)`), but I guess that it is given by template deduction and maybe reference collapsing rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is okay and it is **portable/standard-compliant**.

This is called template specialization and you can read more on this topic [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization)

Template specialization is writing a specific handler for a specific invoke.
In your code, you have two specializations.
The first receives a rvalue reference(e.g. integer literal like 5) and returns an `int`.

The second one receives a lvalue reference(e.g. the variable b who is of type int an have a value of 5) and returns a lvalue reference.

In the default case, you're trying to print the param using `std::stringstream`.